# How to recover after an accidental reboot during upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I was updating my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 and during the work of the update program there was an electricity blackout in my house. When i tried to open the system the recovery console + some lines saying that sth. might be wrong with the filesystem opened and it keeps appearing even after pressing ctrl+D (which should let Ubuntu load normally).

How to revert update changes or fix the system from the console? Can anyone help me?

The console also says that the filesystem is 'read-only' when I try to use `apt-get` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is a case by case thing. Depending when the upgrade was interrupted you may or not be able to recover from there, but the most easier solution is doing a backup of your system and installing anew the latest version.

Anyone may be able to recover, but if you are witless and ain't willing to go back and forth from support the best method is backup and reinstalling.

Comment: what about if the filesystem is too big? I wonder if it could be possible to backup the essential only? I wonder if there is some tool that could do that like restore point on windows..

Comment: @AquariusPower I normally only backup modified /etc files and my home directory, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after a crash during 11.10 to 12.04 upgrade, this command completed the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

but as you say the problem is its saying the file system is read only .

Answer (score 0):

unmout file system and  make "check file system" then mount it again this would help
i think something wrong with your drive .